# HTML How to TRULY center a <div> element?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am just starting a new webpage and set up a Nav-bar at the top of my page. My home button/logo is set to the left of the Nav-bar, and I want to set a series of buttons to navigate to my other pages in the center of the Nav-bar.

The problem is, the logo and title push the "centered" <div> slightly to the right. If I remove the logo, then it's centered. How do I center my .nav-container even though it's being pushed to the right?

Here is my CSS:

```
.toolbar {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 60px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: #1976d2;
color: white;
font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-container{
display: flex;
margin: 0 auto;
gap: 10px;
align-items: center;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <img
      src="logo.png"
      alt="logo"
    />
    <span>My Title</span>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <a>Button1</a>
      <a>Button2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to anyone that can help me learn.

I tried using "margin: 0 auto;" for my .nav-container which does center it, but with other elements in the toolbar it gets pushed around.

I want this <div> to be centered no matter what.

I've also tried all forms of "position" such as relative, fixed, inherit, etc.

Comment: If the logo and the title will be always on the left, why not declare them as absolute?

Answer (score -2):

Add these to your css code

```
img{
    position: fixed;
}
span{
    position:fixed;
    padding: 230px ;
}
```

I will hope resulve your problem!